# Ошибка при получении пользователя из Active Directory c#

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

Подскажите, выходит ошибка при получении пользователя из AD: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". Хотя на компе где пишется программа, работает все нормально, а когда запускаешь на другом компе, выходит ошибка.

```
private void SearchUser(string Login)
{
    try
    {
        string filter = string.Format("(&(ObjectClass={0})(sAMAccountName={1}))", "person", Login);
        string domain = "DC=main,DC=russianpost,DC=ru";
        string[] properties = new string[] { "fullname" };

        DirectoryEntry adRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(adRoot);
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOption.All;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(properties);
        searcher.Filter = filter;

        SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

        string displayName = directoryEntry.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
        string displayMail = directoryEntry.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
        string displaytelephoneNumber = directoryEntry.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
        byte[] data = directoryEntry.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value as byte[];

        MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(data);

        pictureEdit1.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(s);
        labelControl1.Text = displayName;
        labelControl2.Text = "Эл.почта: " + displayMail;
        labelControl3.Text = "тел: " + displaytelephoneNumber;
        btn_UserName.Caption = displayName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); }
}

private void MyForm_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchUser(Environment.UserName);
}
```

Comment: Сколько много букв.. а зачем плодить столько лишних сущностей? Типа `string display*` По вопросу: где exception ошибки то? Какая строка, в чем заключается ошибка, и тд.

Comment: Чтобы увидеть весь стек ошибки надо: не `ex.Message` а `ex.Tostring()`

Comment: NewView спасибо, после того как заменил на ex.ToString(), проблему нашел.

Comment: Незачто,знания - сила :)